# Access violation exception when using a DLL function

Tags: c++, dll

I created a simple DLL as part of my C++ exercises, but I'm getting an access violation exception when invoking DLL function. Here is the DLL's header file(I doubt the CPP will be usefull here):

```
#pragma once

namespace MathFuncs
{
class MyMathFuncs
{
public:
    // Returns a + b
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);

    // Returns a - b
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Subtract(double a, double b);

    // Returns a * b
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Multiply(double a, double b);

    // Returns a / b
    // Throws DivideByZeroException if b is 0
    static __declspec(dllexport) double Divide(double a, double b);
};
}
```

And here is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    double (__cdecl *MYPROC)(double,double);
    /* get handle to dll */
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("DLLExample.dll"); 
if(hGetProcIDDLL == NULL)
    throw;
   /* get pointer to the function in the dll*/
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL,"Add"); 
    if(lpfnGetProcessID)
        throw;
    MYPROC = (double (__cdecl *)(double,double))lpfnGetProcessID;
    if(MYPROC)
        throw;

    double x = MYPROC(5.5,5);

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is the DLL in the same folder where your main program is run from?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here:

```
FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL,"Add"); 
if(lpfnGetProcessID)  // <-- error!
    throw;
MYPROC = (double (__cdecl *)(double,double))lpfnGetProcessID;
if(MYPROC)  // <-- error!
    throw;

double x = MYPROC(5.5,5);
```

If `lpfnGetProcessId` has an address, you're throwing an exception. If not, you later try to call it (boom!).

You're going to want to decorate your functions with `extern "C"` to make sure they are exported as user-friendly names. This means they can't be inside a class:

```
namespace MathFuncs
{
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double, double);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without code to your DLL, one can only speculate, and the naming you've chosen seems to change mid-stream, but it looks like you're doing the following:

1) load the dll and throw an exception if this fails... ok.
2) locate a function in the dll that seems to add two values together -- but you throw an exception if this succeeds? Since you're not throwing an exception, NULL was returned and thus you failed to locate the function.
3) Call the function -- which is at NULL and so you're going to fail here.

I suspect the problem is that you are not accounting for C++ name mangling. You can either change the function name in your call to GetProcAddress() to account for it correctly, or you can declare the function with `extern "C"` to remove mangling.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the method `MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add()` is actually exported as simple "Add", like in your `GetProcAddress` call?

I suspect there is some form of C++ name *mangling* involved.

You may want to use **DUMPBIN /EXPORTS** from the command line to see the actual exported method name.

Moreover, if the return value of `GetProcAddress` is *not* `NULL` (see your `if` test), the function succeeds: why do you `throw`?

Note also that using your DLL would be simpler if you adjust your class header file in such a way to use it in both exports and imports, e.g.

```
#if defined(MATHFUNCS_EXPORT) // Inside DLL implementation
#define MATHFUNCS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else   // Outside DLL
#define MATHFUNCS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // MATHFUNCS_EXPORT

class MyMathFuncs
{
public:

  static MATHFUNCS_API double Add(double a, double b);
  ...
};
```

In this way the client can just `#include` your header file (and link with corresponding .lib file), without using `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`.

Comment: @RiskX: You're welcome. And if you find our answers useful, you may want to click the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Access violation exception when using a DLL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428423/access-violation-exception-when-using-a-dll-function/12428696#12428696) is the correct answer but it's kind of hard to interpret - the problems I see are:

1. The checks are backwards - if we fail to get a function pointer, we continue, and we only throw if we successfully get a function pointer.
2. The member functions should be exported fine since the functions are static, but we fail to get a function pointer because the DLL doesn't export a function called "Add" - the actual name will be mangled and can be found in the .map file, if generated.
3. Since we didn't find a function pointer, we're then casting NULL to the function pointer type and trying to call it, so that's where we get our access violation.

The code should be:

```
FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL,"**MangledAddFunctionName - see .map file**");
if(lpfnGetProcessID == NULL)
    throw;
MYPROC = (double (__cdecl *)(double,double))lpfnGetProcessID;
if(MYPROC == NULL)
    throw;

double x = MYPROC(5.5,5);
```